# How to Create a Searchable List Field in a Salesforce Custom Object Without Multiple Related Objects?

Tags: salesforce

I'm new to Salesforce and facing a challenge with custom objects. I need to create a field in a Salesforce custom object that functions as a list. This list should be fillable either through an API or manual input. Importantly, I want to enable searching for records based on partial values within this list.

I'm looking for a straightforward approach to achieve this. Initially, I considered creating two additional objects: a related object and a junction object for a many-to-many relationship. However, this seems like overkill since my primary goal is just to display the information and enable search functionality.

In a similar app called 'KINTONE', I accomplished this easily by creating a table field with a single column and populating it through an API using a key.

Is there a simpler way to replicate this functionality in Salesforce, ideally without setting up multiple related objects? Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I tried with two more custom objects, I was able to do that, But I want a simpler way

Answer (score 0):

Multiselect picklist might be close to what you're after (screen mockup would help here). Technically they are stored as semicolon-separated values. There are some quirks hidden with them though so read up a bit first, for example https://blog.insycle.com/salesforce-multi-select-picklists

Another option would be to do nothing. Plain old text field(255), populate it however you want. Salesforce's top bar search is fuzzy matching (based on Apache Solr I think) so your data should show up nicely even if not structured in any special way. Should handle long text fields too (but that'd be "just" the search, you can't effectively filter by long text fields in reports or WHERE clauses so stick to 255?).

If your company uses "tags" that could be another neat way to do it but I don't think they're available in Lightning experience...